# accessing over network path

Tags: c#, path

I try to create a file in a server using the following code

```
String path = @"\\192.1.1.55\\d$:\\Scripts\\list.txt";
using (File.Create(path));
richTextBox1.SaveFile(path, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```

It gives System.NotSupportedException 
The given path's format is not supported.

I also tried

```
String path = "\\\\192.1.1.55\\d$:\\Scripts\\list.txt";
using (File.Create(path));
richTextBox1.SaveFile(path, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```

I need to create files and access them over the network with the ip of the server that has files,

Answer (score 5):

[Share](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/share-files-and-folders-over-the-network-from-windows-vista-inside-out) some folder on server, for example `Scripts` and use this path:

```
String path = @"\\192.1.1.55\Scripts\list.txt";
```

Comment: what if I want to access the C or D drive of the server ?

Comment: @user3880883 you can share whole drive, it's similar as folder

Comment: @user3880883 can you accept my answer or should I improve it?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the : after the D$ and it should work.

I now realized that you also have an @ at the beginning of the path string, therefore, change the path to this:

```
String path = @"\\192.1.1.55\d$\Scripts\list.txt";
```

A better approach would be to map the network path to a drive and to use that while saving.

For instance, map network drive R (for richtextbox) to \\192.1.1.55\d$, then change your path variable to G:\Scripts\list.txt

Answer (score 0):

use the following code:

```
String path = "\\\\192.1.1.55\\d$\\Scripts\\list.txt";
using (File.Create(path));
richTextBox1.SaveFile(path, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```

as per microsoft site:

The SaveFile method enables you to save the entire contents of the control to an RTF file that can be used by other programs such as Microsoft Word and Windows WordPad. If the file name that is passed to the path parameter already exists at the specified directory, the file will be overwritten without notice

I don't think there would be any need for the statement: using (File.Create(path)); 
Also, if you are using richtextbox. you should save it as list.rtf.